# Visual Studio 2010 Professional: Cannot find include file "new.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So I just got the Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I created a simple mfc application, added some code and did not change any of the project settings. When I try to compile it I got this errer:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cadmenu, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 10/15/2013 3:44:26 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\cadmenu.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(54):  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'new.h': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This also happens if I create a new mfc app and do not add any code. I searched the entire computer, there is no new.h.

I understand that this is because the new.h file is not in the include directory, but this does not make any sense because I just did a complete install of visual studio 2010 professional. I tried uninstall, deleting all Visual Studio files and then re-install it but the problem persists. Can anyone tell me what is going on and how can I fix this? Thank you very much!

---

I'm using Windows 8 on a 64-bit machine. I tried Googling this problem all day and no good result.

Comment: What is the result if you create an MFC application and **don't** add any code?

Comment: same thing. It can't find new.h.  I think it's because every mfc app includes afx.h and afx.h includes new.h, and new.h is not in my directories.

Comment: `<new.h>` is in Visual Studio's standard include path: <VS installation directory>\VC\include. This should be in your include path. See [VC++ Directories Property Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee855621%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details on setting up the include directories.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that there is no new.h file in this directory :(

Comment: This means that your installation is broken. This can happen if you installed Visual Studio without uninstalling an existing Beta first. There are also reports that an installation will fail if you install a commercial edition without uninstalling an existing Express edition first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just installed VS2015 and had the same problem.  It seems that new.h used to live off the VC folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include) and now lives in the SDK folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt).  If you include this in your list of include folders it will compile past this point.

[image]

Comment: It also need add C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt to library path.

Answer (score 5):

Just had this problem when trying to build with **VS2017 Build Tools**, too...

Solved it by adding the package "Windows Universal CRT SDK" to the install manually.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project, then go  to Properties, go to Configuration Properties, VC++ Directories, and in the Include Directories: $(VCInstallDir)include;. That is if you have the new.h in the directory specified, ie your installationDir\include

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was because my solution had project build targets referring to the Windows SDK 10.0.10240, but the Visual Studio 2017 installer had, during a mere upgrade of Visual Studio, promptly removed the 10240 SDK as well as the Windows 8.1 SDK which my solution also needed.

I had to go to Invidual Components in the installer and manually re-check the Windows SDK 10.0.10240 and Windows 8.1 SDK, and now I got 3 GB worth of files back again.

Lesson learnt: The Visual Studio 2017 installer can do much more than just upgrade, if you let it "upgrade" to another minor release.

I can also recommend verifying so that the Windows Universal C Runtime (UCRT) is checked since it seems to reside under the `ucrt` subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me after importing an old VS2003 solution into VS2017.

To fix it, I had to change "Windows SDK version" in project settings > "Generic" to the latest "10.x.x.x" version available from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i solved it by removing all "Microsoft Visual c++ Redistributable" installations and after that, repairing the VS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install VS2010 SP1, it should help